# JavaFX Task updateValue throws IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have a simple application with a single JavaFX window. I'm sending in data to an Azure IoTHub inside a for loop. This for loop is in a JavaFX Task, and the for loop has a small delay (Thread.sleep(300)) so progress can be shown on the UI. I have 2 labels I want to update during the data transmission, always showing the latest sent in data. I have the following helper class for this:

```
public class DataHelper {

  private StringProperty date = new SimpleStringProperty();
  private StringProperty count = new SimpleStringProperty();

  public DataHelper() {
  }

  public DataHelper(String date, String count) {
    this.date.setValue(date);
    this.count.setValue(count);
  }

  //getters  and setters
}
```

And here is my sendErrorsToHub method inside my UI controller class:

```
  private void sendErrorsToHub(List<TruckErrorForCloud> toCloud) {
    DataHelper dataHelper = new DataHelper("", "");
    Task task = new Task<DataHelper>() {
      @Override
      public DataHelper call() {
        try {
          int i = 0;
          for (TruckErrorForCloud error : toCloud) {
            Thread.sleep(300);
            i++;
            String strMessage = Utility.toPrettyJson(null, error);
            if (strMessage != null) {
              Message msg = new Message(strMessage);
              msg.setMessageId(java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString());
              client.sendEventAsync(msg, null, null);
            }
            updateProgress(i, toCloud.size());
            DataHelper dh = new DataHelper(error.getErrorTimeStamp().substring(0, error.getErrorTimeStamp().length() - 9),
                                           String.valueOf(error.getCount()));
            updateValue(dh);
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
      }

      @Override
      protected void updateValue(DataHelper value) {
        super.updateValue(value);
        dataHelper.setDate(value.getDate());
        dataHelper.setCount(value.getCount());
      }

      //succeeded method omitted
    };
    dateValue.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.dateProperty());
    countValue.textProperty().bind(dataHelper.countProperty());
    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());
    new Thread(task).start();
  }
```

When I run the application, I constantly get `IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread`exceptions, inside the `updateValue` method. As far as I understand the documentation, the whole point of the `updateValue` method, that it runs on the Application thread, and it can be used to pass a custom object, which can be used to update the UI.

What am I doing wrong then?

The bottom of the stacktrace with my classes is the following:

```
at eu.mantis.still_rca_simulator.gui.DataHelper.setDate(DataHelper.java:28)
at eu.mantis.still_rca_simulator.gui.GuiController$1.updateValue(GuiController.java:166)
at eu.mantis.still_rca_simulator.gui.GuiController$1.call(GuiController.java:155)
at eu.mantis.still_rca_simulator.gui.GuiController$1.call(GuiController.java:138)
```

(138 is the line Task task = new Task(), 155 updateValue(dh);, 166 dataHelper.setDate(value.getDate());)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`updateValue` does not automatically run on the application thread and it's not necessary to run it on the application thread since it takes care of updating the `value` property of `Task` on the application thread.

Your code in the overridden version `updateValue` executes logic on the background thread that needs to be run on the application thread though:

```
dataHelper.setDate(value.getDate());
dataHelper.setCount(value.getCount());
```

The bindings result in the `text` properties being updated from the background thread since the above code runs on the background thread.

In this case I recommend using a immutable `DataHelper` class and updating the ui using a listener to the `value` property:

Remove the `updateValue` override and the `dataHelper` local variable, initialize the gui with empty strings, if necessary, declare `task` as `Task<DataHelper> task` and do the following to update the gui:

```
task.valueProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    if (newValue != null) {
        dateValue.setText(newValue.getDate());
        countValue.setText(newValue.getCount());
    }
});
```

You may also use `Platform.runLater` for those updates, since they don't happen frequently enough to result in issues that could be the result of using `Platform.runLater` too frequently.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. So this listener triggers, whenever updateValue() is called, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. `Task` uses a `AtomicReference` to keep the most recent value but `Platform.runLater` that is used for the update, actually runs at some unspecified time. This means you may not see every intermediate value of the property. (note that the return value of `call` is also used to update the `value` property one last time; this is the reason I added the `null` check)